# Получение текста из файла на сервере

Tags: java, android

Есть файл на сервере http://site.com/test.txt.

Как достать из него текст и сравнить его?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6259377/5812238

Comment: Лучше все это делать с помощью json или xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить текст можно, например, используя [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OkHttpClient mHttpClient;
    private String mText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        try {
            run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://site.com/test.txt")
                .build();

        mHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException  {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                mText = response.body().string();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

А сравнить полученный текст можно методом `equals(...)` класса `String`.